# ODBC Too Many connections acuxdbc

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odbc

I have a production API that connect to a cobol database through ODBC. The ODBC driver sometime pop a too many connections error. I don't think I can do much more to close the connection.

```
Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        OdbcConnection con = new OdbcConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LCM"].ConnectionString);
        try
        {
            using (con)
            {
                
                con.Open();
                
                var result = GetProductsFromDB(searchEntities, con, clientID);
                con.Close();
                OdbcConnection.ReleaseObjectPool();
                con.Dispose();
                stopwatch.Stop();
                result.Total = Convert.ToInt32( stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);
                return result.Data;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            OnActionReport(new ReportActionArgs(ex.Message));
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (con.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                con.Close();
                OdbcConnection.ReleaseObjectPool();
                con.Dispose();
                OnActionReport(new ReportActionArgs("Connection Closed finally"));
            }
        }
```

When I restart the IIS service the issue clear up and everything work as it should. Does someone have faced this issue with an ODBC driver before ?

Comment: Is `con` a cached static field or a local variable

Comment: The variable is just over the try.

Comment: To be honest `ReleaseObjectPool` sounds like a bad idea. You want it to reuse the connection, rather than constantly disconnecting and reconnecting. Also `var con = new OdbcConnection` should be inside the `using` brackets

Comment: I'll try that. Actually I think if this doesn't work I will write my own connection pool that will reuse connections that are open...

Comment: Which RDBMS is this? You should preferably use the official one e.g. `SqlConnection` if you can

Comment: Its a cobol database which I can only access through ODBC

Comment: @user3907939  There is no such thing as a Cobol database,  Cobol is programming language.  The ODBC definition will have the name of the client ( 'DB2, 'Oracle', 'SQL Sever', et al) its using.

Comment: Well they call their database ACUCOBOL-GT data files... I get that cobol is a programming language but this one is an unknown database engine which does not support .net and .net does not support that database engine.

Answer (score 0):

I finally made a custom connection pool that will chose an available open connection. it's been almost two weeks now without an issue.